# php curl not sending headers

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

I'm trying to send headers using php curl - which should be rather simple - but there seems to be an issue.

Running on PHP 7.2 I'm setting the headers with

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('My-custom-header-name' => 'Header-Value'));
```

When trying to print info before curl_exec with

```
curl_getinfo($ch);
```

I have the following result :

[image]

The header part remains empty, **is it because it shows response headers ? If yes, how to ensure that the headers are set correctly ?**

I have an access to the remote address I'm trying to reach and I can see, well, can't see, the previously set headers. I would like to make sure they are attached to the curl request before investigating somewhere else.

**The same request is working fine from local to remote addr, are there changes between php 7.1 and 7.2 that I'm not aware of ?**

**EDIT :** I added

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
```

but now the following :

```
curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT);
```

gives

```
POST /someurl HTTP/1.1
Host : Some host
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 153
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

I don't see my custom headers.

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your array should be actually an array of lines! not array of different objects.

So, this should make it.

```
array(
    'My-custom-header-name: Header-Value'
    )
```

Like this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     array(
        'My-custom-header-name: Header-Value'
        ));
```

Comment: With this format I can see my headers! Thanks! Now I can focus on why the server gives me a 401 whereas it accept requests from local computer. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to use option `CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT` for the request headers.

> This is only set if the `CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT` is set by a previous call to `curl_setopt()`.

see the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php) for all available option flags.

Comment: I added the CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT in both curl_setopt and curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT), but this time, the curl_getinfo returns nothing ...

Comment: @thiout_p the documentation does not tell to add it to both. it needs to be set before the request is being sent out; `curl_getinfo()` then has the value after the request was sent.

Comment: I was printing curl_getinfo after closing the curl, my bad, I'm updating my post.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this for about 15 minutes before I found out: the syntax of my headers was wrong!

```
Header-Name: Header-Value
```

is the right syntax. If you're including it on the command line, like so,

```
curl -H "Header-Name: Header-Value"
```

be sure to escape characters where needed (Windows and Linux are very different here). If you've got your headers in a file, it's much easier:

```
curl -H @headerFile.txt
```

Verify your request by including -v (lower case) for verbose output:

```
curl -v
```